# What is the correct URL to resolve GeoTools dependencis via Gradle

Tags: maven

I have a build process that was working correctly until last weekend when it suddenly was not able to find some libraries:

- org.geotools:gt-xml:20.3
- org.geotools:gt-opengis:20.3
- org.geotools.jdbc:gt-jdbc-postgis:20.3

The list of repos I am currently using are these:

- maven { url "https://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/" }
- maven { url "https://maven.geo-solutions.it/" }
- maven { url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
- maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo" }

Is there a new official location for the GeoTools libraries ?

Please note this started failing during the last weekend (2020-04-11/12).

Comment: https://www.osgeo.org/foundation-news/new-osgeo-repo/ and https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html

Comment: Well, that was fast.
It works well with https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/ .  
Thanks a lot!
-Felipe

Comment: related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358615/unable-to-build-a-custom-geoserver-wps

Comment: March 2023: I get pointed by https://mvnrepository.com to https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geotools-releases/ ?

Answer (score 4):

The repository had to be moved into new environment. The original plan of the GeoTools/GeoServer projects was to use redirections and make the move transparent for the users. Unfortunately maven redirections proofed to be unreliable.

Some links for reading:

http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2020/04/change-to-maven-repositories.html
https://www.osgeo.org/foundation-news/new-osgeo-repo/
https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html

Comment: So, I made these changes but anyway I have 'Could not find jai_core-1.1.3.jar (javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3). Searched in the following locations:    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/media/jai_core/1.1.3/jai_core-1.1.3.jar'
At the same time, I see that jai_core-1.1.3.jar is available in repo https://repo.osgeo.org...

Comment: Moving mavenCentral() to the end of the repo list solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

We had to add the following to our build.gradle file:

```
    maven {
        url "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release"
    }
```