# GeoTools ShapefileReader "Random Access not enabled" when trying to read files edited by QGIS 3.12?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, java, geotools

I have some code where the relevant part looks like this:

```
private static List<GisShape> shapes(String shapefile) {
    DataStore dataStore;
    try {
        dataStore = getDataStore(GIS_BOUNDARIES + shapefile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    List<GisShape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        SimpleFeatureCollection features = featureSource.getFeatures();
        SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = features.features();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
```

Here's the code for `getDataStore`:

```
private static DataStore getDataStore(final String filename) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    final URL resource = GisBoundariesController.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
    params.put("url", resource);
    logger.info(resource.toString());
    final DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    if(dataStore == null) {
        throw new IOException(filename);
    }
    return dataStore;
}
```

Now here's the weird part... This code has worked fine for years, and still works in my master repo, but as soon as I try to use a file modified by QGIS 3.12, then the code fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Random Access not enabled
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.positionBufferForOffset(ShapefileReader.java:518)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.hasNext(ShapefileReader.java:424)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader.hasNext(ShapefileReader.java:406)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureReader.filesHaveMore(ShapefileFeatureReader.java:170)
    at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureReader.hasNext(ShapefileFeatureReader.java:183)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection$WrappingFeatureIterator.hasNext(ContentFeatureCollection.java:138)
```

What could cause this? With the original shapefiles the code still works fine, but with the slightly modified shapefile, I get the above exception.

Java Geotools version is 22.0.

*UPDATE*

Other clues and things tried:

1. The log shows this just before the failure

> *SEVERE: The following
>       locker still has a lock: read on
>       jar:file:/C:/Users/.../target/boundaries.jar!/gis_boundaries/schools/Schools.shp
>       by org.geotools.data.shapefile.shp.ShapefileReader*

2. Other files which were edited by QGIS 3.12 open just fine; I've narrowed the issue to just one shape file. I tried editing and
   re-saving the shape file, no go. Reverting to the original file works, but I need the updates.
3. Adding `params.put("CREATE_SPATIAL_INDEX", "true");` had no effect

Comment: I think we need to see the contents of `getDataStore()` to be sure but I suspect you don't have an index - try setting CREATE_SPATIAL_INDEX=true in the creation params

Comment: Question updated to show `getDateStore()`. I will try `CREATE_SPATIAL_INDEX` as soon as repo.boundlessgeo.com comes back up (I did a local repo purge and upgrade to latest version just to remove any old library weirdness, then found repo.boundlessgeo.com is down).

Comment: Have you seen this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358183/what-is-the-correct-url-to-resolve-geotools-dependencis-via-gradle/358244#358244?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the repo move. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps in combination solved the issue:

- Purge my local Maven repo, which leads to...
- Update the [Maven repo location for geotools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358183/what-is-the-correct-url-to-resolve-geotools-dependencis-via-gradle/358244#358244)
- Forced upgrade from JDK 8 to JDK 11 (geotools repo SSL cert not in JDK8 CA!)
- Update all geotools dependencies to 23.0 (from 22.0)
- Fix all the missing JAXB dependencies caused by JDK upgrade
- Take the offending shapefile's last good version from git and then re-apply my required edits using QGIS 2.14 instead of QGIS 3.12

It is interesting to note that the purge/upgrade stuff was not sufficient, I did also have to re-edit the shapefile. In conclusion, there's something wrong with QGIS 3.12 that causes it to write out a corrupt file. Unfortunately, I am unable to revert the environment to see if the cause was JUST the corrupt file.